# Finding value of definite integral

Tags: integration

I came across this problem which says:

Let $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \ \mathbb{R}$ be continuous.  Assume that $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\, dt =2$.  Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\sin^2(nt)\,dt$$ equals to

a) $0$

b) $1$

c) $f(1) - f(-1)$

d) Does not exist

I have taken $f(t)=1$ so that it satisfies the given definite integral. Then I see the solution to be $1$. Am I correct? I am looking for a better way to solve it. Please help.

Comment: I don't get it. We know that $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt =2$ and we want to find the limit of $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt$. The limit of a constant? The thing under the $\lim$ sign should be a function or a sequence, otherwise I don't understand what the problem asks for.

Comment: Unless, or course, the problem asks for $\lim 2$, the limit of a constant sequence, which is of course $2$. But I doubt that this is the case.

Comment: @DanShved  sorry sir. The question will be:   Let f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \ R be continuous.Assume that \int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt =2.Then lim \int_{-1}^{1}f(t)sin^2(nt)dt equals to  (a)0  (b)1 (c)f(1)-f(-1)(d)does not exist.

Comment: @budha: Did you learn [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-LebesgueLemma.html)?

Comment: For a starting, the constant $f=1$ is an easy choice, and if the statement is true in this form, (i.e. doesn't depend too much on $f$), then it must give the right result.

Comment: @Pambos No sir, i did not learn it.

Comment: Then, what are the titles of the recent lectures/sections in the book?

Comment: @Berci  Sir, i came across the problem in an exam paper.

Comment: Then you did the best. I personally dislike these quizes with given possible answers, but if that happens, just pick the easiest example. Anyway, the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma could help you, write $\sin^2$ as $1-\cos^2$ then use $2\cos^2x-1=\cos(2x)$..

Comment: @budha: In the exam you didn't have to justify your answer?

Comment: @Pambos You are right ,sir.But i did not like the way i solved it.So i wanted to know the theorem which would be useful to solve it.

Comment: @budha: In my opinion the best approach is what Berci suggested but uses a theorem (lemma) you didn't learn. In  what course did you take the exams?

Comment: @Pambos  I have used the formula as suggested by Berci. \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)(1-cos (2nt))dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dtcos(2nt)dt=\frac{1}{2}\ast 2-0=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\sin^2(nx)=\dfrac{1-\cos{(2nx)}}{2}$.
 
Then $$\displaystyle{\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\sin^2(nt)\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\,dt-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\cos(2nt)\,dt=1-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\cos(2nt)\,dt}.$$
From [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-LebesgueLemma.html) ( [proof](http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_08/rl_lemma.pdf) )we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\cos(2nt)\,dt=0.$$
Therefore $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\sin^2(nt)\,dt=1.}$